# Spring autherization http security redirection, session issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring http security(Enablewebsecurity) to manage sessions.
But the issue I am facing is, whenever I start the application, the app is opening always home page instead of going to login page. The requirement here is if session is out, need to go login page.
Also session needs to time out for 30minutes. Is there any wrong with below code,

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();

public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding session management,

```
 http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
         .sessionManagement()
            .invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
```

and in application property, you need to add session timeout.

```
 server.servlet.session.timeout=30m
```

Comment: Thanks. sessionManagement works for my requirement. Anyway to auto redirect after 30m?

Comment: add login URL in the .invalidSessionUrl(""/sign-in") , it will redirect to sign-in mapping after 30min

Comment: tried, but the page remains same page. After clicking refresh, then only it is redirecting to login page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .permitAll() after the antmatcher and try again